# need help in linq

Tags: .net, sql, linq

I need help in linq

```
from refoffence in Ref_OffenceCodes join
offenceCodeMatrix in INF_OffenceCodeMatrixes on refoffence.OffenceCodeId equals offenceCodeMatrix.OffenceCodeId
where refoffence.Code=="1909"
select new {offenceCodeMatrix.StandardPenaltyUnits * offenceCodeMatrix.StandardDollarAmount }
```

I need muliplication of StandardPenaltyUnits and StandardDollarAmount as a result.

Please debug the query.

Answer (score 3):

Well, one problem is that you're trying to create an anonymous type with a multiplication operation, but you're not specifying a name. Why are you using an anonymous type at all? You could try:

```
from offenceCode in Ref_OffenceCodes
join codeMatrix in INF_OffenceCodeMatrixes
on offenceCode.OffenceCodeId equals codeMatrix.OffenceCodeId
where offenceCode.Code=="1909"
select codeMatrix.StandardPenaltyUnits * offenceCode.StandardDollarAmount
```

However, it's hard to tell what's wrong as you only provided the failing code, without any indication of the way in which it's failing. The final line *was* a problem, but it may not have been the only one.